# Optimize my Mysql query to get stock status

Tags: php, mysql

This is my mysql query:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(jb_qty) FROM tbl_transactions WHERE jb_Type=1 AND jb_s_Id=$s_Id) AS purqty, 
    (SELECT SUM(jb_qty) FROM tbl_transactions WHERE jb_Type=2 AND jb_s_Id=$s_Id) AS salqty
FROM tbl_transactions LIMIT 1
```

to get the stock status (`jb_type` `1` is purchase and `2` is sales).

I want the current stock status as well from this (like `purqty-salqty`) and need a better query to get these results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could easily improve here. First, you could eliminate the sub-queries and just use a single query with `case` expressions, so the same rows will only be processed once. Second, since the `jb_s_Id` condition is the same for both queries, you could move it out to the `where` clause, again, to reduce the amount of rows the query needs to process:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE jb_type WHEN 1 THEN jb_qty END) AS purqty,
       SUM(CASE jb_type WHEN 2 THEN jb_qty END) AS salqty
FROM   tbl_transactions
WHERE  jb_s_Id = $s_Id
```

**EDIT**:
To answer the question in the comments, if you want to subtract salqty from purqty, you could just use the `-` operator between both expressions:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE jb_type WHEN 1 THEN jb_qty END) AS purqty,
       SUM(CASE jb_type WHEN 2 THEN jb_qty END) AS salqty
       SUM(CASE jb_type WHEN 1 THEN jb_qty END) - 
       SUM(CASE jb_type WHEN 2 THEN jb_qty END) AS diff
FROM   tbl_transactions
WHERE  jb_s_Id = $s_Id
```

A more elegant way, though, would be to use a subquery, so you don't have to repeat the same expressions twice:

```
SELECT purqty, salqty, purqty - salqty
FROM   (SELECT SUM(CASE jb_type WHEN 1 THEN jb_qty END) AS purqty,
               SUM(CASE jb_type WHEN 2 THEN jb_qty END) AS salqty
        FROM   tbl_transactions
        WHERE  jb_s_Id = $s_Id) t
```

Comment: How to subtract salqty from purqty within the query?